# php header and messages on login/registration form

Tags: php, message

I keep getting more than 1 message popping up on my registration form.  Could anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I keep looking at it and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Register form

```
 <?php include_once("config.php");?>
 <?php if( !(isset( $_POST['register']))) { ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header id="head" >
            <p>Please Register</p>
            <p><a href="register.php"><span id="register">Register</span></a></p>
        </header>

    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="register-wrapper">
            <form method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="usn" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                        <input type="password" id="passwd" maxlength="30" required name="password" />
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label for="conpasswd">Confirm Password : </label>
                        <input type="password" id="conpasswd" maxlength="30" required name="conpassword" />
                    </li>
                    <li class="buttons">
                        <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
                        <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="location.href='login.php'" />
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
} else {
    $usr = new Users;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $_POST['password'] == $_POST['conpassword'] ) {
        echo $usr->register($_POST);    
    } else {
        echo "Password and Confirm password not match";
        exit;
    }

    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

    $sthandler = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $sthandler->execute(array(':username'=>$username));

    if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        echo ('<br> Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');
    }else{
        echo  "username is free";
    }
}
?>
```

Register function page

```
 public function register() {
        $correct = false;
            try {
                $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
                $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(:username, :password)";

                $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
                $stmt->execute();
                return "Registration Successful <br/> <a href='index.php'>Login Now</a>";
            }catch( PDOException $e ) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
     }
```

This is the message I keep getting. I need 1 or the other to display. Not both at the same time. PLUS, this is the 1st time I try and register j123 so I'm not sure how I get my username to display that the username is really already used.

```
Registration Successful

Sorry, the username j123 is already in use.
```

Comment: register() should be called after *all*  the checks, and if no errors are returned. you only do a password check before calling it

Comment: Or the checks should be in register()

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely change that.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, look:

Change it:

```
if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        echo ('<br> Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.');
    }else{
        echo  "username is free";
    }
```

For it:

```
if ( $sthandler->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        echo ('<br> Sorry, the username '.$_POST['username'].' is already in use.'); exit();
    }else{
        echo  "username is free";
    }
```

Only add "exit();" after the echo when the count return more than 0. This command will stop the script.